# Custom HTML button to open in new tab

Tags: html, css, wordpress

```
<a href='http://[e2pdf-view id="3"]'><button>Preview your form</button></a>
```

Hello, I have created this button through HTML for previewing application form designed in gravity form, Now I want it to open it in a new tab whenever I click on this button. Anyone, please help.

Comment: Are you creating a button or a link?  You should really pick one or the other.  Either one can be styled to *look like* the other.

Comment: It's a button but works as a link.

Comment: If it's a button, remove the `<a>` element and put the functionality you want in the button.  If it's a link, remove the `<button>` element and style the link how you want.  Trying to use both will cause problems.

Comment: I have done that too, and it opens in a new tab too, but it shows nothing and says "about.blank blocked"

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a target to the link:

```
<a href='http://[e2pdf-view id="3"]' target='_blank'><button>Preview your form</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute `target="_blank"`:

```html
<a href="..." target="_blank">Preview your form</a>
```

In addition you should use only `<a>` tag and style it to look like a button instead of using both `<a>` and `<button>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<a type="button" href='http://[e2pdf-view id="3"]' target='_blank'>Preview your form</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='http://[e2pdf-view id="3"]' target='_blank'> <button>Preview your form</button> </a>
```